# image gallery with slideshow option

Tags: php, thumbnails

hi everyone im new to PHP I'm looking for an image gallery with slideshow mix script with preview pane, 
like :

---

```
(thumb 1) (thumb 2) (thumb 3)
(thumb 4) (thumb 4) (thumb 5) etc.
```

---

...where clicking a thumb the main image ll appear, but i ve only next, previous, close options in main image i need slide show option also can anyone pls help me out in dis

Anyone have a script like this to recommend? can anyone pls help me in dis thanks in advance.
 this is my .js file

```
(function($) {
var opts = {}, 
    imgPreloader = new Image, imgTypes = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'], 
    loadingTimer, loadingFrame = 1;
```

$.fn.fancybox = function(settings) {
        opts.settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.fancybox.defaults, settings);

```
    $.fn.fancybox.init();

    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var o = $.metadata ? $.extend({}, opts.settings, $this.metadata()) : opts.settings;

        $this.unbind('click').click(function() {
            $.fn.fancybox.start(this, o); return false;
        });
    });
};

$.fn.fancybox.start = function(el, o) {
    if (opts.animating) return false;

    if (o.overlayShow) {
        $("#fancy_wrap").prepend('<div id="fancy_overlay"></div>');
        $("#fancy_overlay").css({'width': $(window).width(), 'height': $(document).height(), 'opacity': o.overlayOpacity});

        if ($.browser.msie) {
            $("#fancy_wrap").prepend('<iframe id="fancy_bigIframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
            $("#fancy_bigIframe").css({'width': $(window).width(), 'height': $(document).height(), 'opacity': 0});
        }

        $("#fancy_overlay").click($.fn.fancybox.close);
    }

    opts.itemArray  = [];
    opts.itemNum    = 0;

    if (jQuery.isFunction(o.itemLoadCallback)) {
       o.itemLoadCallback.apply(this, [opts]);

        var c   = $(el).children("img:first").length ? $(el).children("img:first") : $(el);
        var tmp = {'width': c.width(), 'height': c.height(), 'pos': $.fn.fancybox.getPosition(c)}

       for (var i = 0; i < opts.itemArray.length; i++) {
            opts.itemArray[i].o = $.extend({}, o, opts.itemArray[i].o);

            if (o.zoomSpeedIn > 0 || o.zoomSpeedOut > 0) {
                opts.itemArray[i].orig = tmp;
            }
       }

    } else {
        if (!el.rel || el.rel == '') {
            var item = {url: el.href, title: el.title, o: o};

            if (o.zoomSpeedIn > 0 || o.zoomSpeedOut > 0) {
                var c = $(el).children("img:first").length ? $(el).children("img:first") : $(el);
                item.orig = {'width': c.width(), 'height': c.height(), 'pos': $.fn.fancybox.getPosition(c)}
            }

            opts.itemArray.push(item);

        } else {
            var arr = $("a[@rel=" + el.rel + "]").get();

            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                var tmp     = $.metadata ? $.extend({}, o, $(arr[i]).metadata()) : o;
                var item    = {url: arr[i].href, title: arr[i].title, o: tmp};

                if (o.zoomSpeedIn > 0 || o.zoomSpeedOut > 0) {
                    var c = $(arr[i]).children("img:first").length ? $(arr[i]).children("img:first") : $(el);

                    item.orig = {'width': c.width(), 'height': c.height(), 'pos': $.fn.fancybox.getPosition(c)}
                }

                if (arr[i].href == el.href) opts.itemNum = i;

                opts.itemArray.push(item);
            }
        }
    }

    $.fn.fancybox.changeItem(opts.itemNum);
};

$.fn.fancybox.changeItem = function(n) {
    $.fn.fancybox.showLoading();

    opts.itemNum = n;

    $("#fancy_nav").empty();
    $("#fancy_outer").stop();
    $("#fancy_title").hide();
    $(document).unbind("keydown");

    imgRegExp = imgTypes.join('|');
    imgRegExp = new RegExp('\.' + imgRegExp + '$', 'i');

    var url = opts.itemArray[n].url;

    if (url.match(/#/)) {
        var target = window.location.href.split('#')[0]; target = url.replace(target,'');

        $.fn.fancybox.showItem('<div id="fancy_div">' + $(target).html() + '</div>');

        $("#fancy_loading").hide();

    } else if (url.match(imgRegExp)) {
        $(imgPreloader).unbind('load').bind('load', function() {
            $("#fancy_loading").hide();

            opts.itemArray[n].o.frameWidth  = imgPreloader.width;
            opts.itemArray[n].o.frameHeight = imgPreloader.height;

            $.fn.fancybox.showItem('<img id="fancy_img" src="' + imgPreloader.src + '" />');

        }).attr('src', url + '?rand=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999999) );

    } else {
        $.fn.fancybox.showItem('<iframe id="fancy_frame" onload="$.fn.fancybox.showIframe()" name="fancy_iframe' + Math.round(Math.random()*1000) + '" frameborder="0" hspace="0" src="' + url + '"></iframe>');
    }
};

$.fn.fancybox.showIframe = function() {
    $("#fancy_loading").hide();
    $("#fancy_frame").show();
};

$.fn.fancybox.showItem = function(val) {
    $.fn.fancybox.preloadNeighborImages();

    var viewportPos = $.fn.fancybox.getViewport();
    var itemSize    = $.fn.fancybox.getMaxSize(viewportPos[0] - 50, viewportPos[1] - 100, opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum].o.frameWidth, opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum].o.frameHeight);

    var itemLeft    = viewportPos[2] + Math.round((viewportPos[0] - itemSize[0]) / 2) - 20;
    var itemTop     = viewportPos[3] + Math.round((viewportPos[1] - itemSize[1]) / 2) - 40;

    var itemOpts = {
        'left':     itemLeft, 
        'top':      itemTop, 
        'width':    itemSize[0] + 'px', 
        'height':   itemSize[1] + 'px'  
    }

    if (opts.active) {
        $('#fancy_content').fadeOut("normal", function() {
            $("#fancy_content").empty();

            $("#fancy_outer").animate(itemOpts, "normal", function() {
                $("#fancy_content").append($(val)).fadeIn("normal");
                $.fn.fancybox.updateDetails();
            });
        });

    } else {
        opts.active = true;

        $("#fancy_content").empty();

        if ($("#fancy_content").is(":animated")) {
            console.info('animated!');
        }

        if (opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum].o.zoomSpeedIn > 0) {
            opts.animating      = true;
            itemOpts.opacity    = "show";

            $("#fancy_outer").css({
                'top':      opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum].orig.pos.top - 18,
                'left':     opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum].orig.pos.left - 18,
                'height':   opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum].orig.height,
                'width':    opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum].orig.width
            });

            $("#fancy_content").append($(val)).show();

            $("#fancy_outer").animate(itemOpts, opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum].o.zoomSpeedIn, function() {
                opts.animating = false;
                $.fn.fancybox.updateDetails();
            });

        } else {
            $("#fancy_content").append($(val)).show();
            $("#fancy_outer").css(itemOpts).show();
            $.fn.fancybox.updateDetails();
        }
     }
};

$.fn.fancybox.updateDetails = function() {
    $("#fancy_bg,#fancy_close").show();

    if (opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum].title !== undefined && opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum].title !== '') {
        $('#fancy_title div').html(opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum].title);
        $('#fancy_title').show();
    }

    if (opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum].o.hideOnContentClick) {
        $("#fancy_content").click($.fn.fancybox.close);
    } else {
        $("#fancy_content").unbind('click');
    }

    if (opts.itemNum != 0) {
        $("#fancy_nav").append('<a id="fancy_left" href="javascript:;"></a>');

        $('#fancy_left').click(function() {
            $.fn.fancybox.changeItem(opts.itemNum - 1); return false;
        });
    }

    if (opts.itemNum != (opts.itemArray.length - 1)) {
        $("#fancy_nav").append('<a id="fancy_right" href="javascript:;"></a>');

        $('#fancy_right').click(function(){
            $.fn.fancybox.changeItem(opts.itemNum + 1); return false;
        });
    }

    $(document).keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 27) {
            $.fn.fancybox.close();

        } else if(event.keyCode == 37 && opts.itemNum != 0) {
            $.fn.fancybox.changeItem(opts.itemNum - 1);

        } else if(event.keyCode == 39 && opts.itemNum != (opts.itemArray.length - 1)) {
            $.fn.fancybox.changeItem(opts.itemNum + 1);
        }
    });
};

$.fn.fancybox.preloadNeighborImages = function() {
    if ((opts.itemArray.length - 1) > opts.itemNum) {
        preloadNextImage = new Image();
        preloadNextImage.src = opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum + 1].url;
    }

    if (opts.itemNum > 0) {
        preloadPrevImage = new Image();
        preloadPrevImage.src = opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum - 1].url;
    }
};

$.fn.fancybox.close = function() {
    if (opts.animating) return false;

    $(imgPreloader).unbind('load');
    $(document).unbind("keydown");

    $("#fancy_loading,#fancy_title,#fancy_close,#fancy_bg").hide();

    $("#fancy_nav").empty();

    opts.active = false;

    if (opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum].o.zoomSpeedOut > 0) {
        var itemOpts = {
            'top':      opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum].orig.pos.top - 18,
            'left':     opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum].orig.pos.left - 18,
            'height':   opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum].orig.height,
            'width':    opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum].orig.width,
            'opacity':  'hide'
        };

        opts.animating = true;

        $("#fancy_outer").animate(itemOpts, opts.itemArray[opts.itemNum].o.zoomSpeedOut, function() {
            $("#fancy_content").hide().empty();
            $("#fancy_overlay,#fancy_bigIframe").remove();
            opts.animating = false;
        });

    } else {
        $("#fancy_outer").hide();
        $("#fancy_content").hide().empty();
        $("#fancy_overlay,#fancy_bigIframe").fadeOut("fast").remove();
    }
};

$.fn.fancybox.showLoading = function() {
    clearInterval(loadingTimer);

    var pos = $.fn.fancybox.getViewport();

    $("#fancy_loading").css({'left': ((pos[0] - 40) / 2 + pos[2]), 'top': ((pos[1] - 40) / 2 + pos[3])}).show();
    $("#fancy_loading").bind('click', $.fn.fancybox.close);

    loadingTimer = setInterval($.fn.fancybox.animateLoading, 66);
};

$.fn.fancybox.animateLoading = function(el, o) {
    if (!$("#fancy_loading").is(':visible')){
        clearInterval(loadingTimer);
        return;
    }

    $("#fancy_loading > div").css('top', (loadingFrame * -40) + 'px');

    loadingFrame = (loadingFrame + 1) % 12;
};

$.fn.fancybox.init = function() {
    if (!$('#fancy_wrap').length) {
        $('<div id="fancy_wrap"><div id="fancy_loading"><div></div></div><div id="fancy_outer"><div id="fancy_inner"><div id="fancy_nav"></div><div id="fancy_close"></div><div id="fancy_content"></div><div id="fancy_title"></div></div></div></div>').appendTo("body");
        $('<div id="fancy_bg"><div class="fancy_bg fancy_bg_n"></div><div class="fancy_bg fancy_bg_ne"></div><div class="fancy_bg fancy_bg_e"></div><div class="fancy_bg fancy_bg_se"></div><div class="fancy_bg fancy_bg_s"></div><div class="fancy_bg fancy_bg_sw"></div><div class="fancy_bg fancy_bg_w"></div><div class="fancy_bg fancy_bg_nw"></div></div>').prependTo("#fancy_inner");

        $('<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tr><td id="fancy_title_left"></td><td id="fancy_title_main"><div></div></td><td id="fancy_title_right"></td></tr></table>').appendTo('#fancy_title');
    }

    if ($.browser.msie) {
        $("#fancy_inner").prepend('<iframe id="fancy_freeIframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
    }

    if (jQuery.fn.pngFix) $(document).pngFix();

    $("#fancy_close").click($.fn.fancybox.close);
};

$.fn.fancybox.getPosition = function(el) {
    var pos = el.offset();

    pos.top += $.fn.fancybox.num(el, 'paddingTop');
    pos.top += $.fn.fancybox.num(el, 'borderTopWidth');

    pos.left += $.fn.fancybox.num(el, 'paddingLeft');
    pos.left += $.fn.fancybox.num(el, 'borderLeftWidth');

    return pos;
};

$.fn.fancybox.num = function (el, prop) {
    return parseInt($.curCSS(el.jquery?el[0]:el,prop,true))||0;
};

$.fn.fancybox.getPageScroll = function() {
    var xScroll, yScroll;

    if (self.pageYOffset) {
        yScroll = self.pageYOffset;
        xScroll = self.pageXOffset;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
        yScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        xScroll = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    } else if (document.body) {
        yScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
        xScroll = document.body.scrollLeft; 
    }

    return [xScroll, yScroll]; 
};

$.fn.fancybox.getViewport = function() {
    var scroll = $.fn.fancybox.getPageScroll();

    return [$(window).width(), $(window).height(), scroll[0], scroll[1]];
};

$.fn.fancybox.getMaxSize = function(maxWidth, maxHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight) {
    var r = Math.min(Math.min(maxWidth, imageWidth) / imageWidth, Math.min(maxHeight, imageHeight) / imageHeight);

    return [Math.round(r * imageWidth), Math.round(r * imageHeight)];
};

$.fn.fancybox.defaults = {
    hideOnContentClick: false,
    zoomSpeedIn:        500,
    zoomSpeedOut:       500,
    frameWidth:         600,
    frameHeight:        400,
    overlayShow:        false,
    overlayOpacity:     0.4,
    itemLoadCallback:   null
};
```

})(jQuery);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image gallery you are talking about is actually a client-side script and built using JavaScript. It is not affected by the underlying server langauge you are using, i this case PHP.

There are hundreds of different JavaScript image galleries. Try this article for a starting point: [35 Useful jQuery Plugins for Slideshows, Graphs and Text Effects](http://www.noupe.com/jquery/35-useful-jquery-plugins-for-slideshows-graphs-and-text-effects.html)

From my own knowledge, the best JavaScript gallery is built on top of jQuery and called [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)